# Restoring data from MySQL (.psc file ) backup file

Tags: mysql, migration, backup, restore

Is it possible to restore a MySQL database from the physical database files. I have a directory that has the following file type:

client.psc

but i dont know how to restore it.
I have to restore data in MySQL and then migrate it to SQL Server !!!
I have downloaded nevicut software for mysql ..

Can anyone tell me proper steps for this task.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: how did you do your backup? what'S the file content?

Comment: hi .. I have third party backup want to restore at my side ..

Comment: which third party? and what is the format of the file?

Comment: hi... database backup file is with .psc extension file which need to be restored n then the database usable after that it would migrate to SQLServer..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question.
But you have to restore it with Navicat.
Double click on the DB you want to restore (if it does not exist just create it).
Select Backup-->Restore Backup, and then select the .psc file